# Node MySQL - reusable connection module

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, database-connection, node-mysql

**Question Updated:**

---

The solution should detail a simplified, proper model of a **Node connection module** allowing for the re-use of the connection by any module of a Node application needing to connect to a database. That way, the question might be useful for anyone with connection module issues in Node.

The answer might even include a way to pass in different credentials in order to connect to different tables or databases with a single function call from anywhere in an app.

---

I wrote a script that utilized a number of simple modules to allow a user to post login data, have that data validated on the server, and if correct, receive a response of success. A very basic login functionality.

**The problem:** One user can log-in, but any more log-in attempts before I restart the server fail to connect to the database.

It appears that, because I'm declaring the connection in a variable in my module db_connect and requiring that module, the connection can't be re-used. It's being declared in the required module, and I had mistakenly believed that calling the variable in each connection attempt would recreate the connection. It doesn't.

**The solution:** As suggested by barry in the comments, in the db_connect module, I need to make the connection functionality a function rather than a variable, so I can then create the connection from within my validation script.

**How can I do this?** I'm trying to output the connection object when calling the `createConnection()` function, which is an exported method of db_connect.

**db_connect:**

```
console.log('db_connect module initialized');
var mysql      = require('mysql');

function createConnection(){
    var connection = mysql.createConnection({
        host     : 'localhost',
        user     : 'root',
        password : '',
        database : 'officeball'
    });
}

exports.createConnection = createConnection();
exports.mysql = mysql;
```

**validator:**

```
console.log('validator module initialized');
var connect = require("./db_connect");

function validate(username, password, callback){

    var createConnection = connect.createConnection();
    //the idea is for this to return the object, connection, 
    //which opens a new connection

    connection.connect(function (err){
        if (err) return callback(new Error('Failed to connect'), null);
        console.log('Connection with the Officeball MySQL database openned...');

        connection.query('select username,password,fname,lname,rank,active from users where username=?',
                username,
                function(err,rows,fields) {
                    connection.destroy();
                    console.log('...Connection with the Officeball MySQL database closed.');
                    if (err)
                        return callback(new Error ('Error while performing query'), null);
                    if (rows.length !== 1)
                        return callback(new Error ('- [Anomaly] - Failed to find exactly one user'), null);

                    if (rows[0].password === password & rows[0].active === "yes") {

                        var result = new Object;

                        result.username = rows[0].username;
                        result.password = rows[0].password;
                        result.fname = rows[0].fname;
                        result.lname = rows[0].lname;
                        result.rank = rows[0].rank;

                        return callback(null, result);

                    } if(rows[0].active !== "yes"){

                        return callback(new Error ('User account not active.'), null);

                    }else {

                        return callback(new Error ('Login credentials did not match.'), null);

                    }

                });


    });
};

exports.validate = validate;
```

**Console log** *(originally, there was a connection error, but after my fix-attempt, the error is about the method)*:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\officeball\node_scripts>node index.js
application initialized
server module initialized
login module initialized
validator module initialized
db_connect module initialized
sale module initialized
Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8080/
User username1 is attempting login...
TypeError: Property 'createConnection' of object #<Object> is not a function
    at Object.validate (C:\xampp\htdocs\officeball\node_scripts\custom_modules\v
alidator.js:6:33)
    at C:\xampp\htdocs\officeball\node_scripts\custom_modules\login.js:61:13
    at callbacks (C:\xampp\htdocs\officeball\node_scripts\node_modules\express\l
ib\router\index.js:164:37)
    at param (C:\xampp\htdocs\officeball\node_scripts\node_modules\express\lib\r
outer\index.js:138:11)
    at pass (C:\xampp\htdocs\officeball\node_scripts\node_modules\express\lib\ro
uter\index.js:145:5)
    at Router._dispatch (C:\xampp\htdocs\officeball\node_scripts\node_modules\ex
press\lib\router\index.js:173:5)
    at Object.router (C:\xampp\htdocs\officeball\node_scripts\node_modules\expre
ss\lib\router\index.js:33:10)
    at next (C:\xampp\htdocs\officeball\node_scripts\node_modules\express\node_m
odules\connect\lib\proto.js:193:15)
    at multipart (C:\xampp\htdocs\officeball\node_scripts\node_modules\express\n
ode_modules\connect\lib\middleware\multipart.js:93:27)
    at C:\xampp\htdocs\officeball\node_scripts\node_modules\express\node_modules
\connect\lib\middleware\bodyParser.js:64:9
```

Comment: Make `var connection = login.connection;` the first line of your `validate` function rather than having it as one-time initialization code.

Comment: Ahh. Not opening the connection again might be a problem ...

Comment: Changed this. Still the error. @barry-johnson

Comment: Ahh - I wasn't reading your `db_connect` closely enough, sorry about the red herring suggestion. The issue is still the same one I thought it was - you're destroying the connection you are creating only once (in `db_connect`) so you can't reuse it. Various ways to address, but quickest in the code would be to make `db_connect.connection` a function which gets a new mysql connection. then in your main code, do a `connection=login.connection()` to get a new connection each time. Let me know if that makes sense. I can post more explicityly as an answer if you need further direction.

Comment: @barry-johnson I did that, but now I'm making `login.connection` a function... How can I access the `connect` method of the object if it's a function?

Comment: I can check this again tomorrow but can't do much for you now. Quick read of your new code raises a couple of issues. You aren't returning anything from your connection() method in db_connect, but I believe you probably intended to. Also, you are calling login.connection when you have only defined login.connect in the module. Suggestion - try to do this in one source file and then refactor when you have it working.

Comment: Reading it quickly again, I strongly suggest just getting this working in one file. The number of connect/connection vars, properties and functions makes this hard to reason converse about clearly. See if just changing your `var connection = connect.connection()` in your main file to be `var connection = mysql.createConnection(...)` help. From my quick read, I think the rest of your code looks reasonable.

Comment: Ok, I think, based on your earlier comment, that I almost have this figured out. I'm going to rewrite this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem was primarily what I mentioned in my comment, so I will make it an answer. Don't hurt yourself slapping your forehead. :-) See my inline comments below. You had one method invocation too many, an unreturned result, and a misnamed variable - otherwise, it works just fine.

**db_connect.js**

```
console.log('db_connect module initialized');
var mysql      = require('mysql');

function createConnection(){
    var connection = mysql.createConnection({
        host     : 'localhost',
        user     : 'root',
        password : '',
        database : 'officeball'
    });
    // ************ NOTE BELOW FOR CHANGE **************
    // You didn't return anything from this function. You need to return the connection
    return connection;
}
// ************ NOTE BELOW FOR CHANGE **************
// You are exporting a single connection by invoking createConnection();
// exports.createConnection = createConnection();
// what you want is:
exports.createConnection = createConnection;
exports.mysql = mysql;
```

**validator.js**

```
function validate(username, password, callback){
    // ************ NOTE BELOW FOR CHANGE **************
    // You had:
    // var createConnection = connect.createConnection();
    // but based on your code, you wanted to write this instead:
    var connection = connect.createConnection();

    /// ... REMAINDER OMITTED, because it was A-OK and this is already a long page
};
```

If you make those <strike>two</strike> three changes, you should be good to go. As ever, feel free to ask for any clarifications if it would be helpful.

**Update** This is how I am calling it - as you can see, I had it try to do it ever 2 seconds.

**jt-test.js**

```
var v = require('./validator');
var timers = require('timers');
var connections = 0;

timers.setInterval(function(){
    v.validate('bagehot','foo',function(err,result){
        if (err)
            console.log('failed', err);
        else
            console.log('success! ',result);
    });
},2000);
```

**result**

```
Connection with the Officeball MySQL database openned...
...Connection with the Officeball MySQL database closed.
success!  { username: 'bagehot',
  password: 'foo',
  fname: 'walter',
  lname: 'bagehot',
  rank: 12 }
Connection with the Officeball MySQL database openned...
...Connection with the Officeball MySQL database closed.
success!  { username: 'bagehot',
  password: 'foo',
  fname: 'walter',
  lname: 'bagehot',
  rank: 12 }
Connection with the Officeball MySQL database openned...
...Connection with the Officeball MySQL database closed.
success!  { username: 'bagehot',
  password: 'foo',
  fname: 'walter',
  lname: 'bagehot',
  rank: 12 }
Connection with the Officeball MySQL database openned...
...Connection with the Officeball MySQL database closed.
success!  { username: 'bagehot',
  password: 'foo',
  fname: 'walter',
  lname: 'bagehot',
  rank: 12 }
```

And so on. It runs indefinitely. Complete code for the three files is in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/barry-johnson/9485669)

Comment: Made these changes. Now back to square 1. Second attempt fails.

Comment: `C:\xampp\htdocs\officeball\node_scripts>node index.js
application initialized
server module initialized
login module initialized
validator module initialized
db_connect module initialized
sale module initialized
Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8080/
User username1 is attempting login...
Connection with the Officeball MySQL database openned...
...Connection with the Officeball MySQL database closed.
User username1 logged in successfully.
User username1 is attempting login...
User username1 triggered error: Error: Failed to connect`

Comment: Please post how you are calling it. Before I answered last night, I tested it by making two connections. See update above.

Comment: I'm calling it here https://gist.github.com/anonymous/9495481 - Is that wrong somehow?

Comment: It's just fine other than the fact that it doesn't work at all. Where is loginFail()? where is loginSucceed()? how is login.js? supposed to know about the app defined in server.js? Where was `validator` included? Honestly, I am trying to be helpful, but it is rather frustrating when I ask for your code and you upload something that doesn't even run. I have again fixed your code and added it to [the original gist](https://gist.github.com/barry-johnson/9485669). I adapted it for GET rather than POST because there was no way I was going to waste time making a form for it as well.

Comment: Ok, new to JS here, offering a bounty for the trouble. I'll fix it.

Comment: I'll add the bounty in 7 hours when the time is up.

Comment: I thought it was a simple problem, sorry.

Comment: No real trouble. I understand being new to something. The challenge is that, non working X code obscures the problem with Ye. Also, I do think you will find some of this stuff will be easier to get traction with if you work on it in one file and then refactor. One great thing about JS is tremendous flexibility to just write code and run it. Obviously that's no way to develop a real app, but it's a great way to try things out while you're getting the hang of it. I personally like it because it's easier for me to spot type errors when I'm not having to mentally track the `exports` chain.

Answer (score 0):

You can checkout my `emysql` package.

https://www.npmjs.org/package/emysql

https://github.com/yanke-guo/enhanced-mysql-pool

Maybe it's some kind of outdated with the most recent `node-mysql` package, but still functional.